# Trouble removing tests from default registry

Tags: c++, cppunit

I have a trouble in finding a way to un-register tests that were added using the `CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION` macro in `CppUnit`. I am attempting to optimize my main test runner by un-registering all tests that I do not care about for a given test, but when tests are added to the default registry using above method and then retrieved using `CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry()`, the tests don't seem to be un-registerable.

Although registering each test to a named registry instead of the default registry using `CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_NAMED_REGISTRATION` does the purpose it requires me to edit nearly 300 existing tests. Is there a method to  localize this solution?

Comment: my tests are file local, using CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE. I compile them with a #ifdef STREAMLINED_UNITTESTING preprocessor switch around CPPUNIT_TEST macros for specific tests to skip for a quick build of just the unittests, and disable that for some integration/system tests. But that would still require editing a bunch of files for you, sorry.

Comment: After a lot of research, I determined it was either impossible or very difficult to accomplish my goal of localization. Since the required change was pretty straight forward, just extensive, I built a short script to automate the changes required. No harm done, just a little sloppier than I would have hoped